# FragmentActivity blows up with a simple xml file

Tags: android

I have a very simple layout file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- put map fragment here -->
    <fragment
          android:id="@+id/map"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment">
     </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, I have a class that extends FragmentActivity that begins like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_view);
```

When it hits that setContentView, I get a runtime exception. I can't figure out why.

Added:

Well, I'm not including the rest of the onCreate, because it never reaches it. The relevant parts of logcat seem to be:

> 05-09 22:31:35.604: E/dalvikvm(922): Could not find class
>   'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions', referenced from
>   method com.molavi.homeworkfive.LocalMap.setUpMap 05-09 22:31:35.604:
>   W/dalvikvm(922): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 470
>   (Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions;) in
>   Lcom/molavi/homeworkfive/LocalMap; 05-09 22:31:35.635:
>   D/dalvikvm(922): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0002 05-09
>   22:31:35.744: E/dalvikvm(922): Could not find class
>   'com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView', referenced from method
>   com.molavi.homeworkfive.LocalMap.setUpMapIfNeeded 05-09 22:31:35.744:
>   W/dalvikvm(922): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 466
>   (Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/MapView;) in
>   Lcom/molavi/homeworkfive/LocalMap; 05-09 22:31:35.744:
>   D/dalvikvm(922): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x000b 05-09
>   22:31:35.754: E/dalvikvm(922): Could not find class
>   'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment', referenced from
>   method com.molavi.homeworkfive.LocalMap.onCreate 05-09 22:31:35.764:
>   W/dalvikvm(922): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 467
>   (Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment;) in
>   Lcom/molavi/homeworkfive/LocalMap; 05-09 22:31:35.784:
>   D/dalvikvm(922): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x003f 05-09
>   22:31:35.814: I/dalvikvm(922): Could not find method
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onDestroy, referenced
>   from method com.molavi.homeworkfive.LocalMap.onDestroy 05-09
>   22:31:35.814: W/dalvikvm(922): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method
>   3401: Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment;.onDestroy ()V
>   05-09 22:31:35.814: D/dalvikvm(922): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at
>   0x0002 05-09 22:31:35.856: I/dalvikvm(922): Could not find method
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onLowMemory, referenced
>   from method com.molavi.homeworkfive.LocalMap.onLowMemory 05-09
>   22:31:35.864: W/dalvikvm(922): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method
>   3402: Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment;.onLowMemory ()V
>   05-09 22:31:35.864: D/dalvikvm(922): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at
>   0x0005 05-09 22:31:35.904: I/dalvikvm(922): Could not find method
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onPause, referenced
>   from method com.molavi.homeworkfive.LocalMap.onPause 05-09
>   22:31:35.904: W/dalvikvm(922): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method
>   3403: Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment;.onPause ()V
>   05-09 22:31:35.934: D/dalvikvm(922): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at
>   0x0002 05-09 22:31:35.944: I/dalvikvm(922): Could not find method
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onResume, referenced
>   from method com.molavi.homeworkfive.LocalMap.onResume 05-09
>   22:31:35.964: W/dalvikvm(922): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method
>   3404: Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment;.onResume ()V
>   05-09 22:31:35.964: D/dalvikvm(922): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at
>   0x0005 05-09 22:31:35.984: I/dalvikvm(922): Could not find method
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onSaveInstanceState,
>   referenced from method
>   com.molavi.homeworkfive.LocalMap.onSaveInstanceState 05-09
>   22:31:35.984: W/dalvikvm(922): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method
>   3405:
>   Lcom/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment;.onSaveInstanceState
>   (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V 05-09 22:31:36.014: D/dalvikvm(922): VFY:
>   replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0005 05-09 22:31:36.024: D/dalvikvm(922):
>   DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0d4f at 0x04 in
>   Lcom/molavi/homeworkfive/LocalMap;.setUpMap 05-09 22:31:36.044:
>   D/dalvikvm(922): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x0d4e at 0x15 in
>   Lcom/molavi/homeworkfive/LocalMap;.setUpMap 05-09 22:31:37.464:
>   E/ThrottleService(287): problem during onPollAlarm:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing stats:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/iface_stat_all:
>   open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

But I don't get that because it seems to be saying it can't find the methods on mapFragment, but mapFragment definitely has those methods.

Comment: Is the above xml your `activity_map_view` layout? What is the rest of your `onCreate`? Also, `fill_parent` has been deprecated in favor of `match_parent`.

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your exception.

Comment: 1. Do you have a Google Maps API key?  2. Are you including the Google Maps binaries?  3.  If you have a key, are you including it in your manifest?

Comment: Yep, Yep, Yep. I suppose I could post my manifest, but it's getting pretty huge already.